Dummit and Foote: construction of nonabelian groups of order $p^3$
In Dummit and Foote's textbook on abstract algebra, they discuss the nonabelian groups of order $p^3$, namely the Heisenberg group $\text{Heis}(\mathbb{F}_p) $ and the other group $G_p$. However, I am having trouble following a part of its argument for their construction.
In the textbook, they start with two groups $H$, $K$ and build a (nonabelian) group $G$ as a semidirect product $G = H \rtimes K$ with respect to some homomorphism $\phi: K \to \text{Aut}(H)$. Since $|H| |K| = p^3$, either $|H| = p^2$ or $|H| = p$. Then it is found that all the cases with $|H|= p$ are abelian, so $|H| = p^2$, and there are two such groups up to isomorphism. For the case $ H \cong Z_p \times Z_p $, $K = Z_p$, we have a homomorphism $\phi: Z_p \to \text{Aut}(Z_p\times Z_p) \cong \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/(p))$, so $p \mid \lvert \text{Aut}(H) \rvert$. By Cauchy's theorem there is an element of order $p$ in $\text{Aut}(H)$, so there exists a nontrivial homomorphism $\phi$. Similarly for the case $H \cong Z_{p^2}$ we have $ p \mid \lvert\text{Aut}(H)\rvert = p(p-1)$, so there exists a nontrivial homomorphism.
The next part is where I have trouble: They say for case 1, let $H = \langle a\rangle \times \langle b \rangle$, $K = \langle x\rangle$, and let $K$ act on $H$ by $x\cdot a = ab$ and $x \cdot b = b$. Then we have the presentation of the group
$$ H \rtimes K = \left\langle x, a, b \mid a^p = b^p = c^p = 1, ab=ba, xax^{-1}=ab, xbx^{-1} = b \right\rangle. $$
For case 2, let $H = \langle y \rangle$, $K = \langle x\rangle$, and let $K$ act on $H$ by $x\cdot y = y ^{1+p}$. Then the presentation of the group is
$$ H \rtimes K = \left\langle x, y \mid x^p = y^{p^2} = 1, xyx^{-1}=y^{1+p} \right\rangle .$$ How on earth did they come up with these specific actions? Is there any intuition behind them? Also, how would I show that some arbitrary action I just wrote down is in fact well-defined.

For case 1:
The automorphism group of $Z_p\times Z_p$ is isomorphic to the group of invertible $2\times 2$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_p$. If a matrix $A$ has multiplicative order $p$, then it satisfies the polynomial $t^p-1$, which factors over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ as $(t-1)^p$. Thus, either the matrix is the identity (which doesn't have order $p$) or it has Jordan canonical form equal to
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
1 & 1
\end{array}\right).$$
That is, it is conjugate to this matrix, and so it is this matrix up to an automorphism of $\mathsf{GL}(2,p)$. So we may as well assume that our map $K\to\mathrm{Aut}(H)$ sends the generator of $K$ to the automorphism corresponding to this matrix.
But this matrix acts on $\langle a\rangle\times\langle b\rangle$ by sending $a$ to $ab$ and sending $b$ to $b$. Thus, we let the generator $x$ of $K$ act on $a$ by sending it to $ab$ and act on $b$ by sending it to $b$.
For case 2: the automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ is cyclic of order $p(p-1)$. If we think of it as being the additive group of integers modulo $p^2$, then the automorphisms are given by multiplication by a constant. The map $a\mapsto ka$ has order $r$ if and only if $k^r\equiv 1\pmod{p^2}$ and $k^s\not\equiv 1\pmod{p^2}$ for any $1\lt s\lt r$. Since
$$(p+1)^p = p^p + \sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\binom{p}{i}p^{p-i} + 1 \equiv 1\pmod{p^2}$$
(because every coefficient in the sum is a multiple of $p$), the order of $p+1$ is either $1$ or $p$. It is not $1$, since $p+1\not\equiv 1\pmod{p^2}$, so multiplication by $p+1$ is an automorphism of order $p$. So up to an automorphism of $\mathrm{Aut}(Z_{p^2})$, we can assume that the image of $x$ in $\mathrm{Aut}(Z_{p^2})$ corresponds to "multiplication by $p+1$" in the additive group of integers modulo $p^2$, which corresponds to the map $y\mapsto y^{p+1}$ in the multiplicative group generated by $y$. So we can let $x\in K$ act on $\langle y\rangle$ by mapping $y$ to $y^{p+1}$.
Now, there are a few "up to isomorphism"s above, which in principle require you to check that a different choice of action would yield an isomorphic group. In case 2, the elements of order $p$ are precisely the powers $(p+1)^k$ with $1\leq k\leq p-1$, which amount to picking $x^k$ as a generator for $K$ instead of $x$, so this is easy. In case 1 there is a bit more work to do, but you can also prove that picking a different representative of the operator will yield and isomorphic group.
You know that these actions are well defined because they are given by group homomorphisms into the automorphism group.

So for the case of the Heisenberg group, we can in fact use another matrix $A$ that is conjugate to the Jordan canonical form by some element $S \in \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p) $ as the action, and this choice isn't the only one we can use?

@JonathanHuang it will result in a different presentation but an isomorphic group, the isomorphism witnessed by the matrix $S$ you use, taking elements $Sa$ and $Sb$.
